# Fitting a Markov Model with Linear Transition Probabilities

Tags: optimization, markov-chains, nonlinear-optimization, mathematical-modeling, maximum-likelihood

I have data which I model as 50 rounds of a Markov chain with linear transition probabilities
$$
P_{ij} = \begin{cases}
\alpha_1 i + \alpha_0                       & \mbox{ if } j=i-1 \\
\beta_1 i + \beta_0                         & \mbox{ if } j=i+1 \\
1-(\alpha_1+\beta_1) i - (\alpha_0+\beta_0) & \mbox{ if } j=i \\
0                                           & \mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Note:

1. The linear probabilities mean this can't be well defined on $\mathbb{Z}$, to resolve that I bound $0\le i\le 50$.
2. The resultant constraints on $\alpha_{0,1},\beta_{0,1}$ are dependent and not very nice. I don't mind making do with neater box constraints because I have some initial guesses for them.

What I have are samples drawn from the probability distribution $P^{50} e_k$ resulting from this process for several known starting points $k$.

I currently use (somewhat arbitrarily) a simulated annealing type process to minimize the covariance of the empirical data and the computed probability distribution given $\alpha_{0,1},\beta_{0,1}$, but I would like something more robust. My question is:

- Has this type of fitting problem been studied? If so, where can I find results on it?
- Are there any similar results on fitting Markov chains that I can use to get ideas on how I could look for a solution?
- Are there other optimization methods (not necessarily assuming the data results from a Markov chain) I should look into?